# What is the efficient way to send Arduino Serial data Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, arduino

I am send serial data from the Arduino via ble to an Android App.  What would be the most efficient way to send (from Arduino) and receive (to Android) this data.

One idea is to transmit the data from the Arduino using the Serial.print in a CSV format.

```
 Serial.print(speedValue);
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.print(distanceValue);
 Serial.print(",");
 Serial.print(timeValue);
```

Do you have a better idea.

Comment: Looks good to me. Since you would be sending this from a loop (which runs continuously), you may also want a delimiter for every transmit to distinguish from the next one. Also, make sure to have some delay between each transmission.

Comment: I was thinking a start character like Serial.print("#"); and stop character Serial.print("~";

Answer (score 0):

The CSV way is probably not the best way, as it require I/O to write on a file.
Instead you could send data directly through BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy) if you have a BLE module you can send directly the data to your android device, and process it on the device.

Alternatively you can think about a client/server architecture where your Arduino device send data to a restFul server, and your android device get the data from this same server.

One last method could be to send your data with a M2M protocol such as [MQTT](http://mqtt.org) if you don't have a very high load of data to send.